# length of numpy.unique on a 2D list of shape (1,*)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-3.7

When calling `numpy.unique` on a list of shape `(1, X)`, for instance `a = [[1,2]]`, `len(numpy.unique(a))` returns `X` rather than, as i'd have expected, 1. Generally speaking, `numpy.unique` seems to treat `a` as 1D array..

In contrast to this, `len(numpy.array(a))` does return 1.

What is the motivation behind this?

EDIT: python version 3.7.3

Comment: Take another look at the [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).  In the description of `axis`, it says "The axis to operate on. If None, `ar` will be flattened."

Comment: oh, i actually missed that this also happens for more general 2d arrays.. now it makes a little more sense

Comment: Please mark the correct answer if your question was resolved.

Comment: if @WarrenWeckesser formulates his comment into an answer, i will, since he was the first one to give the "correct answer".
FYI my confusion actually came from another oddity that i overlooked:
`numpy.unique([[1], [2,3]])` does not seem to flatten, and the `dtype` is different than if i'd have only same-length lists in the 2D list. Thats why i didn't recognize that the flattening does not only happen in (1,*) shapes, but whenever the shape is "rectangular"

Comment: kawillzocken, the answer by @Akaisteph7 looks fine, so feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you get is because the array is flattened. And the length of `[1,2]` is indeed 2. I believe the reason this is done is just to give the maximum amount of flexibility to the user.

What you were looking for can be achieved by doing this instead:

```
len(np.unique(a, axis=0))
```